# Docker compose up and aws context give error ''* option "up --attach-dependencies" on context type ECS.: unsupported flag. ''

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

Docker compose up to aws ecs gives an error:

> - option "up --attach-dependencies" on context type ECS.: unsupported flag.

I am trying to deploy the docker containers to was ecs using docker compose up. I have aws cli configured and have created docker context using aws.

Below is my docker compose file.
I tried doing `docker compose up dev` and `docker compose up nest-cloud-run` and got the same error as above for each of them.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev:
    image: postgres:15
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    networks:
      - bdnetwork
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgres

  nest-cloud-run:
    image: nest-cloud-run
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - dev
    volumes:
      - './.env:/usr/src/app/.env'
    networks:
      - bdnetwork

  test:
    image: postgres:15
    ports:
      - '5434:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    networks:
      - bdnetwork

networks:
  bdnetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

I tried removing the `--attach-dependencies` flag from docker compose up but was not successful in doing so. I have tried looking for some documentation on this error but have found little help from docker compose and aws cli (ecs). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering suggests that the `"up --attach-dependencies"` option is not supported in the context type ECS when using Docker Compose with AWS ECS (Elastic Container Service).

please go through this documentation on AWS ECS
https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/getting-started/

The "`up --attach-dependencies`" flag is not a standard Docker Compose flag. It is possible that it was added as a custom flag or extension specific to your environment, but ECS does not recognize or support it.

When working with AWS ECS, you typically use the AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) or the AWS Management Console to deploy and manage your containers. Docker Compose, on the other hand, is primarily used for local development and testing environments.

To deploy your containers to AWS ECS, you'll need to use the appropriate ECS deployment methods. This typically involves defining your task and service configurations using the AWS CLI or AWS Management Console and then using the ECS-specific commands to create or update your ECS services.

Comment: thanks for the reply. All the tutorials I have seen perform the following steps: 1. Configure their AWS CLI. -> 2. Create docker context of type ecs. -> 3. Use docker compose up as they did locally to deploy their container to AWS ECS.      /////.  Do you know how to remove the flag error ?

Comment: Also I didn't put the `--attach-dependencies` anywhere in the docker files or the command line. Is there anyway to circumvent this issue?